# Fonts not scaling in UINavigationBar for iOS 7

Tags: ios7, uinavigationbar, xcode5, uifont

I am using Xcode 5 and developing for iOS 7.

I use the following code to change my `UINavigationBar` font style:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                       [UIColor colorWithRed:245.0/255.0 green:245.0/255.0 blue:245.0/255.0 alpha:1.0], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                                       [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.8],UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                                       [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, 1)],
                                                       UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                                       [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-CondensedBold" size:18.0], UITextAttributeFont, nil]];
```

In iOS 6, instead of setting a specific font size, if I put `0.0` instead of `18.0`, the font would automatically scale itself depending on portrait or landscape orientation.

If I set the font size as `0.0` in iOS 7, it doesn't work. The font styles are not applied. The default iOS 7 values are used.

How do I make the `UINavigationBar` font scale automatically in iOS 7?